# Azure SQL Data Warehouse permissions to create an External Table

Tags: security, permissions, azure-synapse

I have a user who needs to run a stored procedure.  Within that stored procedure is a `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` statement.  This statement runs flawlessly when executed by a high-permissioned user.

But when run by a low-permissioned user, the statement fails with the error:

```
Cannot find the object {table name} because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

I have explicitly GRANTED the user the following permissions:

```
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO {user};
GRANT ALTER ANY SCHEMA to {user};
GRANT ALTER ANY EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE to {user};
GRANT ALTER ANY EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT to {user};
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a DENY ALTER ANY SCHEMA in the mix.  Found it, REVOKED it and was successful.  Problem solved.

Comment: Feel free to mark that as the answer.  Self-answers are useful for people arriving at the same issue.